# Showing extension ring of a field is an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $F \subset K$ both be fields and $S \subset K$ be a non-empty set of $K.$ How do I show that $F[S]$ is an integral domain? The case for finite order $S$ is easy because $F[S]$ is just the image of the evaluation homomorphism of the polynomial ring over $F.$ However, I'm pretty clueless on the case of infinitely large $S.$ Is there anything to be said about the structure of $F[S]$ in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F[S]$ is a ring extension of $F$. The elements of $F[S]$ can be viewed as multivariate polynomials $$\sum_\alpha c_\alpha x_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots x_n^{\alpha_n},$$  where $c_\alpha\in F$ and $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in S$, $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\geq 0$, where $n\geq 0$ also varies.

Each such element belongs to $K$ and so $F[S]$ cannot have zero divisors.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. Turns out I was asking a very silly question.